# ogr2ogr commands with cmd

Tags: sql, ogr2ogr, osgeo4w, command-line, shell

I'm trying to run a ogr2ogr command  with cmd. When I run the cmd the Osgeow command prompt just flashes and nothing happens. When I enter my ogr2ogr script directly to the Command Prompt everythinh works fine. My cmd script looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL C:\OSGeo4W64\OSGeo4W.bat ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM 'D:\Testi2\own.SHP'.own WHERE Owner like 'Harr%'" D:\Testi2\own.shp D:\Testi2\All.SHP
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: does it work when you type it at the command line? I suspect you need a return between the bat file and ogr2ogr

Comment: Hi. Yes, it does work when I type it directly to cmd. What do you mean by 'return'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To debug the command, it can be helpful to `echo` it instead of running it, to see if any special characters are throwing things off.  From inside a bat file, do:

```
echo ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM 'D:\Testi2\own.SHP'.own WHERE Owner like 'Harr%'" D:\Testi2\own.shp D:\Testi2\All.SHP
```

Which will print:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM 'D:\Testi2\own.SHP'.own WHERE Owner like 'Harr\Testi2\own.shp D:\Testi2\All.SHP
```

Notice the end of the command is getting screwed up starting at the "%" symbol.  Turns out that from within a batch file, [you have to escape it by doubling it](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) (but not so on the command line!).  So the command becomes:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM 'D:\Testi2\own.SHP'.own WHERE Owner like 'Harr%%'" D:\Testi2\own.shp D:\Testi2\All.SHP
```

And `echo`ing it looks okay now.

And a note about setting up batch files that leverage OSGeo utils-- if you look in the OSGeo4W.bat, you'll see this towards the top:

```
call "%~dp0\bin\o4w_env.bat"
```

That's what actually sets up the environment.  It can simplify things by leaning on that instead:

```
@echo off

REM set up the environment
call C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\o4w_env.bat

REM anything from here on out will run in that context
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM 'D:\Testi2\own.SHP'.own WHERE Owner like 'Harr%%'" D:\Testi2\own.shp D:\Testi2\All.SHP

@echo on
```

Comment: Hi. It's still doing the same thing. Somehow it doesnt understand the sql when its being run via .bat file.

Comment: Ahh, it was the "%" symbol.  I updated my response to answer your actual question :p

Comment: It works now. Thank you.